# How to change some html text using Js code?

Tags: javascript, html, macos

I already google so please don't tell me to google it because I can't understand what I've done wrong. When I press the **Submit** button nothing happens on the website.

Here is my **HTML** file:

```
<button onclick="runThis()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="apples">Hello</h1>

<script>
    function runThis() {
        var getTextID = document.getElementsByTagName("apples");
        getTextID = "Hello guys";
    }
</script>
```

mac user by the way if that makes any difference.

Comment: You are using the wrong selector. `getElementsByTagName()` will look for the element tag name **h1** not the **ID**. Replace your query selector to `document.getElementById("apples")` and to set new content you can use `getTextID.textContent = "Hello guys";` [**Here Is A JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/p25L7oyk/)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for quick reply.

Comment: Very welcome, I have posted my example as a answer. I hope it is useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this;
`document.getElementById("apples")`

Comment: @Aspect, this is not the complete answer of the issues in your code....`getTextID = "Hello guys";` is not going to work in your code....(:

Answer (score 2):

First of all, ***apples*** is not the tag name, it is the *id* of the element. The tag name is ***h1***.

Then `getElementsByTagName()` returns colection. You have to use specific *index* like:

```
getElementsByTagName('h1')[0]
```

Though it should be `getElementsById()` as your are trying to get the element with *id* attribute. Also, *getTextID* refers to the element itself, you have to use the *textContent* or *innerText* property to set the text in the element.

Try the following way:

```js
function runThis(){
    var getTextID = document.getElementById("apples");
    getTextID.textContent = "Hello guys";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runThis()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="apples">Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong selector. 
`getElementsByTagName()` will look for the element tag name **h1** not the **ID**.

Replace your query selector to `document.getElementById("apples")` and to set new content you can use `getTextID.textContent = "Hello guys";`

[**Here Is A JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/p25L7oyk/)

```js
function runThis() {
  var getTextID = document.getElementById("apples");
  getTextID.textContent = "Hello guys";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runThis()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="apples">Hello</h1>
```

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I well get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `querySelector` & `innerHTML`.

```js
function runThis() {
    var getTextID = document.querySelector("#apples");
    getTextID.innerHTML = "Hello guys";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runThis()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="apples">Hello</h1>
```

Please check more here about getElement* and querySelector*: https://javascript.info/searching-elements-dom

Answer (score 0):

The method you are using, getElementsByTagName, returns elements with a tag name, not a single element with an ID like what you want. To fix this part of the issue, add, use getElementById instead:

```
var getTextID = document.getElementById("apples");
```

Secondly, you need to replace the inner text of the element, not the element itself, so you should use innerText:

```
getTextID.innerText = "Hello guys";
```

Fully working demo:

```js
function runThis() {
    var getTextID = document.getElementById("apples");
    getTextID.innerText = "Hello guys";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runThis()">Submit</button>
<h1 id="apples">Hello</h1>
```

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score -2):

```
    function runThis(){
        document.getElementById("apples").innerHTML = "Problem solved ";
    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you changed, and why, for the benefit of the person who is asking who may not understand.